# Getting the result of input from one view to another SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I have this view:

```
struct CreateBoardView: View {
    @State public var BoardName: String = ""

var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
               TextField("Board name", text: self.$BoardName)
              }
          }
}
```

And then, when info is entered in this text field, I want to send it to another view. How to do this?

Comment: Look up in Google for “view model SwiftUI”, or “SwiftUI MVVM” (stands for Model-View-ViewModel). By the way, @State vars should be private - look up also “SwiftUI State Binding”.

Comment: It also \depends on how/if the views relates to each other, using @Binding could be a possibility

Comment: Structure for yourself the view hierarchy and how one is shown by another one. Then use State and binding to update data.

Answer (score 1):

This is a possibility:

```
struct CreateBoardView: View {
    @State var boardName = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            TextField("Board name", text: $boardName)
            AnotherView(boardName: $boardName)
        }.padding()
    }
}

struct AnotherView: View {
    @Binding var boardName: String

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Transfered text: \(boardName)")
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct CreateBoardView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CreateBoardView()
    }
}
```

Also you can use a ViewModel and transfer text through it:

```
struct CreateBoardView: View {
    @StateObject var vm = ViewModel() //Here we create ViewModel, notice vm = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            TextField("Board name", text: $vm.boardName)
            AnotherView(vm: vm)
        }.padding()
    }
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var boardName = ""
}

struct AnotherView: View {
    @ObservedObject var vm: ViewModel //Here we observe ViewModel, notice vm: ViewModel, also you can observe the ViewModel in more views you'll create, not only this one.

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Transfered text: \(vm.boardName)")
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct CreateBoardView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CreateBoardView()
    }
}

//BTW, use caps for first letters in struct and class names, and for variables the first letter should always be small.
```